# Setting up a connection to Oracle on Mac using java

Tags: java, database, oracle, jdbc, connection

I'm trying to connect Oracle database using this [tutorial](http://www.mkyong.com/jdbc/connect-to-oracle-db-via-jdbc-driver-java/)
I have put ojdbc6.jar in the same folder with OracleJDBC.java.

But it gives me an error:

```
-------- Oracle JDBC Connection Testing ------
Where is your Oracle JDBC Driver?
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
at jaa.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:190)
at OracleJDBC.main(OracleJDBC.java:13)
```

Don't understand what is the problem?

Comment: The tutorial tells you to run it as `java -cp ...`, so did you do that, and use the OS X paths to the `.jar` and your compiled class, rather than the Windows paths in their example?

Comment: yes, i'he rune that command and i use my os x path, it runs and do nothing, then i run next command _user-vaio:src apple$ java -cp ojdbc6.jar;OracleJDBC_

Comment: You need both elements of the `cp`, as GyroGearless showed - though I'd slightly prefer the full paths, e.g. `java -cp $PWD/ojdbc6.jar:$PWD OracleJDBC`. That works for me with the code from that site.

Comment: Do I need to save tnsname.ora? it shows -------- Oracle JDBC Connection Testing ------
Oracle JDBC Driver Registered!
Connection Failed! Check output console
java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: IO Error: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection
 at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:419)
 at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.<init>(PhysicalConnection.java:536)
 at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.<init>(T4CConnection.java:228)
 at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:32)

Comment: You don't need a `tnsnames.ora` for this, no. Did you change the values in the `DriverManager.getConnection()` call to something appropriate for the DB you're trying to connect to?

Comment: Yes, i have _connection = DriverManager.getConnection(    "jdbc:oracle:thin:@192.168.101.72:1521/ORCLVB4", "daniyar","Daniyar");_      Where I used **conn daniyar/Daniyar@orclvb4**

Comment: my tnsname.ora should be like this:
  **ORCLVB4=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=
    (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=192.168.101.72)(PORT=1521)))
    (CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=ORCL)))**       and i need to use command **conn daniyar/Daniyar@orclvb4;**

Comment: java.sql.SQLException: Listener refused the connection with the following error:
ORA-12514, TNS:listener does not currently know of service requested in connect descriptor 
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:419)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.<init>(PhysicalConnection.java:536)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.<init>(T4CConnection.java:228)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:32)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:521)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:571)

Comment: You should not be using a TNS alias; the connect string should be `"jdbc:oracle:thin:@192.168.101.72:1521:ORCL"`, where `ORCL` is the SID of the database (which may or may not be the same as the service name).

Comment: I have another question: I can run it using terminal command line. But I need to run it using eclipse, and it gives me an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might be unexpected for a mac user, but it is not enough to drop a jar in a folder to make things work.

Try something like

```
java -cp .:odbc6.jar OracleJDBC
```

Comment: Thank you, but where to try it? in terminal?

Comment: Now it says:-------- Oracle JDBC Connection Testing ------
Oracle JDBC Driver Registered!
Connection Failed! Check output console
java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: IO Error: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection
 at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:419)
 at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.<init>(PhysicalConnection.java:536)
 at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.<init>(T4CConnection.java:228)
 at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:32)
 at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:521)

Comment: Do I need to save tnsname.ora?

Comment: I think there is no need to have a tnsnames.ora for a pure Java JDBC driver (but i haven't been working with Oracle for quite a while, so i might be wrong). Maybe post your connection code and the exact connection URL you use!